# Discrete Uniform Distribution with random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let X be the random variable that records the number of “heads” when two coins are
tossed. Let Y be a random variable with the discrete uniform distribution on the probability space {1, 2, 3}.
Assume that X and Y are independent. Let U be the random
variable defined by U = X + Y .
Find the probability distribution for the random variable U.

How is the probability distribution calculated in this case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check the support of the new rv $Z=X+Y$

$z \in \{1;2;3;4;5\}$

to calculate the probability of each $z$ the easiest way is to construct a $2 \times 2$ table with inside the table the probability of the joint distribution (easy because of independence) then detect all the possible cases for each z

- Example, for $z=2$

$$\mathbb{P}[Z=2]=\mathbb{P}[X=0;Y=2]+\mathbb{P}[X=1;Y=1]=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{3}{12}$$

now you have only to calculate all the other probabilities of $z \in Z$